# line not being created using psedo elements and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a line towards the left side of this image using psedo elements and absolute positioning.  somehow the line is not appearing , the HTML and CSS i have used  for this is pritty straightforward .

HTML :

```
<img src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

CSS :

```
img {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;

}

img:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    right: -15px;
    color: #000;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Why is a line not appearing towards the left side of  the image ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/1/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is a line not appearing towards the left side of the image ?

Because image tag doesn't have content, so `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements are not behave as you expect.

The best thing you can do is to wrap image into helper `inline-block` container:

<sup>(however, I'm not sure what shape `:before` is supposed to be in your case)</sup>

```css
.wrapper img {
    width: 400px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    right: -15px;
    color: #000;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe I made this mistake ! Thanks though !

Answer (score 1):

:before doesn't work for img. You must add it to the wrapper div. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/fq6q4n7L/3/

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
div:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    right: -15px;
    color: #000;
    background: #000;
    display:block;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pseudoelement `:after` is like a tag that would be just before the tag that references ends. THe image tag is an open-only tag, so it can't have an `:after`.

For example, if we had `<p>Text</p>`, the pseudoelement after would me something like this: `<p>Text<after>content</after><p>`
Therefore, logically, it is not posible.